# \Cref{} Figure in Short?

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref

How can we use `\Cref` to obtain the format "**Figs.**" or "**Fig.**" in PDF?

If I only use `\Cref`, then I always get Figures, Figure ...

Comment: What should the plural of **Fig.** be set to? **Figs.**? Please advise.

Comment: @Mico  both .......

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `cleveref` package provides the `\Crefname` macro for the very question you asked. Thus, just write

```
\Crefname{figure}{\textbf{Fig.}}{\textbf{Figs.}}
```

in the preamble, after loading the `cleveref` package.

For more information on this subject, see section 8.1.2 on page 14 of the package's user guide.